# Ways to pass an ArrayList with socket

Tags: java, list, sockets

What is the best way to pass an `ArrayList<Object>` from server to client? 
After i have to put my ArrayList in a `JTable`.

Comment: What have you seen in your search on this? What have you tried? How is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

You have to serialize it when you write to the socket and deserialize when you read from the socket.

Ultimately you're sending Strings on the wire.  Transport doesn't know or care anything about objects on either end of the conversation.  TCP/IP is language independent.

You have many choices to choose from:

1. Java Serializable - this means sending byte code on the wire.
2. XML.  You can use JAXB.
3. JSON.  You can use Jackson.
4. Custom protocol of your own design.